# Remote branch tracking does not change to the new target

Tags: git

I issue git push origin -u for a local branch and the branch is set up track remote_branch and code is pushed.

```
git push origin -u local_branch:remote_branch
```

I then issue the same command again but with a different branch remote_branch_2 name and code is pushed again.

```
git push origin -u local_branch:remote_branch_2
```

Then I check by issuing:

```
git branch -vv
```

It shows the local_branch is tracking remote_branch instead of remote_branch_2.  Why?

Comment: it looks correct,  can you reproduce the problem (and provide us with the commands you have issued)?

Comment: @joran I have provided the commands I issued in the original post.  Two push origin -u to different remote branch, and the git branch -vv to see what it's tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the solution to the problem, I'm just trying to reproduce the problem.

```
git init --bare origin-repo
git clone origin-repo clone

cd clone
touch dummy
git add .
git commit -m "yada"

git push origin master

git checkout -b branch1
git push origin branch1:remote_branch

git checkout -b branch2
git push origin branch2:remote_branch2

git checkout -b local_branch

git branch -vv
git push origin -u local_branch:remote_branch
git branch -vv
git push origin -u local_branch:remote_branch2
git branch -vv
```

the output:

```
* local_branch e7cfe7f yada
...
* local_branch e7cfe7f [origin/remote_branch] yada
...
* local_branch e7cfe7f [origin/remote_branch2] yada
```

which is expected.

@Boon, how does this conform with your actions?

---

@joran, I modified the above steps to reflect what I have done:

```
git init --bare origin-repo
git clone origin-repo clone

cd clone
touch dummy
git add .
git commit -m "yada"

git push origin master

git checkout -b branch1
git push origin -u branch1:remote_branch
git push origin -u branch1:remote_branch2

git branch -vv
```

Note: Previously my output is showing branch1 is tracking remote_branch.  Following your steps here I am not able to get the same results - remote_branch2 is tracked as expected.

Will select your answer as it proves there may be issue on my end (and the git init --bare and clone is very cool!)